# Limit access to npm packages

Tags: npm, artifactory, npm-install, yarnpkg

I'm in the middle of a project and we've decided to start using our own internal private packages, part of the process of deploying this in the company is to ensure that users can only install from our artifactory repo. Is there anyway of restricting access to external npm packages and only allowing users to install from our private repo that anyone can point me towards?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to achieve this is setting up a [local npm repo](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Npm+Registry#NpmRegistry-LocalNpmRegistry) and pointing all users (via `.npmrc` - see [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Npm+Registry#NpmRegistry-SettingtheDefaultRegistry)) to that repo.
This will effectively make your users resolve packages only from your local repo.

This method probably requires that you download the packages your users depend on from the public registry and manually deploy them to the local repo so that they are available for clients requesting them.

Another way would be to put a remote and a local behind a [virtual repo](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Npm+Registry#NpmRegistry-VirtualNpmRegistry) and use [include / exclude](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Common+Settings#CommonSettings-IncludesandExcludesPattern) patterns to allow your users to download *some* packages from the public registry (i.e *npmjs.com*) while limiting all others to be resolved from the local repo (or not at all if they are unavailable in it.).

Comment: I was looking down this path of having a local .npmrc in the project base. I was also looking at a .yarnrc in the base. Thanks for the feedback!